# Conditioning on the length of values in two columns to assign a value

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns.

```
C1  C2  
A  T
T  T
T  G
TTG T
G  GTGA
AAT A
```

I want to go through the dataset, and turn column C1 into either a "D" if the length of it's value is less than C2, or to an "I" if the length is greater than C2

Desired output:

```
C1  C2
A  T
T  T
T  G
I  T
D GTGA
I  A
```

Comment: Try `with(df1, ifelse(nchar(C1) < nchar(C2), 'D', ifelse(nchar(C1) > nchar(C2), 'I', C1)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `case_when` to do this

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(C1 = case_when(nchar(C1) < nchar(C2) ~ 'D',
                          nchar(C1) > nchar(C2) ~ 'I', 
                          TRUE ~ C1))
#   C1   C2
#1  A    T
#2  T    T
#3  T    G
#4  I    T
#5  D GTGA
#6  I    A
```

Comment: Question not related to OPs problem: does `case_when` calculate `nchar(C1)` here once or twice?

Comment: @PoGibas  I guess it should be the number of times we apply the function, probably better would be to create two columns and then remove it later (depends on the dataset size etc)

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked perfectly. I'm not that familiar with using dplyr, so I should probably practice.